# AWS Quicksight monthly summarize in percentage from different csv files

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

**1.** I have a Lambda function that is running monthly, it is running Athena query, and export the results in a CSV file to my S3 bucket.

**2.** Now i have a Quicksight dashboard which is using this CSV file in Dataset and visual all the rows from the report into a dashboard.

*Everything is good and working until here.*

**3.** Now every month I'm getting a new csv file in my S3 bucket, and i want to add a "Visual Type" in my main dashboard that will show me the difference in % from the previous csv file(previous month).

**For example:**

My dashboard is focusing on the collection of missing updates.
In May i see i have 50 missing updates.
In June i got a CSV file with 25 missing updates.
Now i want it somehow to reflect into my dashboard with a "Visual Type" that this month we have reduced the number of missing updates by 50%.

And in month July, i get a file with 20 missing updates, so i want to see that we reduced with with 60% from the month May.

Any idea how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand where you're standing, but I'll assume that you have an S3 manifest that points to an S3 directory and not a different manifest (and dataset) per each file.

If that's your case you could try to tackle that comparison creating a calculated field and using the [periodOverPeriodPercentDifference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/periodOverPeriodPercentDifference-function.html)

Hope this helps!